# CSS Grid: 100% height of top level container doesn't center child elements

Tags: css, css-grid

I have an angular `css-grid` SPA with 3 section, `nav`, `content` and `footer`

```
<div class="body__div--background"  >
  <div class="css-grid-container">
    <app-nav-component></app-nav-component>
    <app-content-component></app-content-component>
    <app-footer-component></app-footer-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `nav` is bootstrap navigation. In `css-grid`, I want that `nav` takes its usual space, `content` takes most of the remaining space and `footer` takes a small space at the bottom

```
.css-grid-container{
  height:100vh; /*height of the container is same ahs height of the view port.*/
  display: grid;
  grid-gap:20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;  /* 1 columns*/
  grid-template-rows: auto 15fr 1fr; /* 3 rows. Auto takes height of navigation, remaining is divided into 2 rows, middle row is 15 times larger than the 3rd row.*/
}

app-nav-component {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

app-footer-component{
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 3 / -1;
}

app-content-component{
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

The `content` could have different types of `Angular` components. From layout perspective, I want all these to be centered w.r.t the `content` section. My issue is that if I have say 2 components, say `home` and `signup` (at any point only one of them would be visible inside `content`) then I have to specify `height:100%` in `css` of both of these. This would become an issue esp. as the list of my components grow.

```
.homepage-component-css-grid-container{
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap:20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;  /* 2 columns*/
}

.div__signup{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}
```

Is there a way by which I specify `height:100%` only in one place and the components inside `content` take up the entire space and get centered. I tried to specify `height:100%` in `content` (and removed from `home` and `signup`) but I noticed that the `home` and `content` didn't centered properly i.e. not centered within the `content` area.

See pics below

height:100 in content area only

```
<div id="content-div">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

#content-div{
height:100%;
}
```

[image]

what I want is this (but for this I have to explicitly specify `height:100` in all the components I want to place inside `content`. I will prefer not to do this to avoid code duplication)

[image]

Comment: You can center it without setting `height: 100%;` to `content-div` - see [codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/vdejMm?editors=1100)

Comment: How high is the parent element of `#content-div`?

Comment: the top level component's height is `100vh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to do it in CSS grid, I would do the following:

1. Give the class `.css-grid-container` the grid property `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;`
2. Define your `app-content-component` as a `display: grid;`.
3. Now all child elements form `app-content-component` are grid items and can be aligned with [justify-self](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#article-header-id-28) and [align-self](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#article-header-id-29).
4. In your case that would be now `align-self: center;` and `justify-self: center;`.

*If you want, you should also have more flexibility in a "content grid" with this way. E.g. you can now give the element `app-content-component` the property `grid-template-rows: 15fr;`*

---

Here's a look:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.css-grid-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

app-nav-component {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  
  padding: 10px;
  background: gray;
}

app-content-component {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  display: grid;
}

login {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;

  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}

app-footer-component{
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 3 / -1;
  
  padding: 10px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="body__div--background">
  
  <div class="css-grid-container">
    
    <app-nav-component>

      {nav}    
    
    </app-nav-component>
    
    <app-content-component>
      
      <login>{login}</login>
        
    </app-content-component>
    
    <app-footer-component>
    
      {footer}
    
    </app-footer-component>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

---

I hope that could help :)

Comment: something very similar worked. I changed the `app-content-component` to `flexbox` and used the following css  (content-div is the top level div in app-content-component). `#content-div{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}`

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to used as this... but if you are putting not as many elements inside content-div, you could use this:

```
#content-div > * {
height: 100%;
}
```

This should take care of all the children in content-div.

Comment: `>*` didn't work. I am not sure if it is because css from parent cannot go to child in angular. I have opened another question for this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816419/selector-not-working-from-parent-to-child-component