# `>*` selector not working from parent to child component

Tags: css, angular

I have the following Angular component

```
<div id="content-div">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I place different components within the div above. My requirement is that all such components should have the `css` rule `height:100%`. Instead of duplicating this code, I tried to use `>*` css but that isn't working.

```
#content-div >* { 
  height:100%;
}
```

Does `>*` doesn't work across components? How could I make a child component take `css` rule from its parent?

Comment: *"The `::ng-deep` pseudo-class selector also has a couple of aliases: `>>>` and `/deep/`, and all three are deprecated. The main reason for that is that this mechanism for piercing the style isolation sandbox around a component can potentially **encourage bad styling practices.**"* - https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/ 
So maybe you need to re-think the styling you are trying to apply to the component ?

Comment: am prettus sure it's the height:100% that it's not working ! because there is not height set to parent

Answer (score 1):

By default Angular encapsulates CSS.  If you want to disabled this you need to do so in your component setup

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  template: `<div class="parent-class">Child Component</div>`,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None  // Use to disable CSS Encapsulation for this component
})
```

Comment: so I add this in the parent component or each child component?

Comment: @ManuChadha to the Child component

Comment: that will not work for me because I want to create a rule in parent which is forced on all children. Writing the rule in all children will lead to duplication and I might forgot to add it in new children in future.

Comment: ah ok, sorry.  I'm not aware of a way to do that in angular.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in the next way:

```
:host /deep/ > * {
   height: 100%;
}
```

But it's very unlikely you should do `*` it's very heavy and slow selector, it's better to limit yourself to something more specific, like the class on container or at least some tag.

Comment: So I learned today that `/deep/`, `>>>` and `::ng-deep` are now all deprecated. https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: didn't know that.. Well by this time you can still use it . They are still supported by the browsers, so currently it's valid approach. Standards change every day..

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the approach. Instead of using `>*`, used `css-grid`. It worked.

```
#content-div{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```